How to convert TypeScript Interfaces and Types to JSON for Fastify Interoperability
I am new to Fastify and I do not want to write JSON schema objects from scratch, but leverage TypeScript Interfaces and Types exposed from an existing Data Access Controller. How can I convert those TS Interfaces/Types into JSON schemas, either at dev-time or runtime, for consumption by Fastify to better support RESTful API validation? Thank you in advance.

Would something like this work?

According to the Fastify documentation you can achieve what you want by using type providers.
In the example below I used the Typebox to generate the TypeScript type and JSON schema-compatible Object to use in the runtime
import Fastify, { type RequestGenericInterface } from "fastify";
import { type TypeBoxTypeProvider } from "@fastify/type-provider-typebox";
import { type Static, Type } from "@sinclair/typebox";

const UserSchema = Type.Object({ username: Type.Optional(Type.String()) });

type UserType = Static<typeof UserSchema>;

const app = Fastify().withTypeProvider<TypeBoxTypeProvider>();

interface RequestPayloadType extends RequestGenericInterface {
  Querystring: UserType;
}

app.get<RequestPayloadType>(
  "/user",
  { schema: { querystring: UserSchema } },
  (req, _) => {
    const result = req.query.username ?? "no-name";
    return result;
  }
);

